# How to delete records from "table2" except the array list values contains in "table2"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
   Using MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = MdlCommonCodes.GetConnectionTempData1, 
        MyDataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select pledgerno From pledger", MyConnection)
        If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Open()
        Using MyDataSet As New DataSet
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, 0)
            Dim DataSetRowCount As Integer = MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            If DataSetRowCount > 0 Then
                Dim PledgerNoArrayList As List(Of String) = (From myRow In MyDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable Select myRow.Field(Of String)("pledgerno")).ToList

               'Deletion

            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

I need to delete records from **table2** except the array list values (`PledgerNoArrayList`) contains in **table2**.

Suppose `PledgerNoArrayList` contains two values as "1000" and "1001". These two values should be exist in **table2** and rest of the records should be deleted from **table2**.

Comment: You need to use `NOT IN` in your `WHERE` clause.  Look it up.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thats the right way...

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298) useful if you want to use parameters for this. There's really no difference between using `IN` and `NOT IN` from that respect. That said, given that you're only using numeric IDs and not text input from the user, simple string concatenation would not be so bad in this case.